Please autofocus the input field when opening duplicate closure dialog in SG
In Staging Ground, when I select "Vote as duplicate" and then click "Submit", the duplicate closure dialog opens, but the input field isn't focused and focus stays on the "Submit" button. Please automatically focus the input field.
I'm tempted to categorize this as a bug, since this is what the regular duplicate closure dialog does.

Use whatever argument you can make to flag this as a bug. Feature requests go into /dev/null.

@Gimby honestly, so do most bug requests. Seems that it has to be a highly disruptive thing for an issue to get attention. SE just breaking working functionality is by now par for the course and such things are very rarely revised, either.

I want to mention that in the beta tests, all or almost all bugs and feature requests reported in the beta team were addressed (some where deferred or not implemented for a few reasons but these were at least addressed) - thanks to the devs for this.

@dan1st OK, I agree that during betas they do pay attention. But overall, the track record for addressing bugs in already published things is...rather poor. SG is new, so for now feedback is taken. But, say, the review queue audits are broken since the end of March. I'd have expected such a problem to have been addressed before June. But it hasn't been even after June. They are just more broken since April

Nice catch! There was code that was trying to automatically focus this, but it wasn't working. I fixed it and now it should be focusing as expected.
